# coffeescript keeps compiling indented code outside the function scope

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Coffeescript is now compiling the following code

```
$ ->
    $("#debug").val "hey"
    for i in [0..3]
        m = new Message(5,5)
        text = "<div>#{m.message[m.message_id]}</div>"
        $("body").append(text)
```

into:

```
  $(function() {
    return $("#debug").val("hey");
  });
  for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
    m = new Message(5, 5);
    text = "<div>" + m.message[t.message_id] + "</div>";
    $("body").append(text);
  }
```

The whole "for" clause is totally outside the jQuery load function. What is going on here? What's wrong with my way of indenting??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a wild guess: you're mixing tabs and spaces for indentation. If your CoffeeScript is this (where, of course `<tab>` is a single tab character):

```
$ ->
    $("#debug").val "hey"
<tab>for i in [0..3]
        m = new Message(5,5)
        text = "<div>#{m.message[m.message_id]}</div>"
        $("body").append(text)
```

then you'll get the output you're seeing and if your tab-stop is set to 4, your eyes won't notice.

Comment: +1 most of the time, that turns out to be the problem. With CoffeeScript you really need to use an editor that turns tabs into spaces or at least set it to a mode where is displays 'invisibles'.

Comment: @Thilo: Same editor "rules" as Python or any other significant whitespace language I suppose.

Comment: Takes me back to makefile days. OTOH, it taught me to look for tabs. And hate them.

Comment: This is exactly where the problem is. Everything is solved after I covert all tabs to spaces.

Comment: @lkahtz: If you can configure your editor to display tabs with a width of 8 and still indent with 4 spaces then you might be able to avoid this sort of unpleasantness in the future.